# Is HTML-linked content still subject to the CC-BY-SA license?

Tags: mit, github, cc-by-sa, gitlab

If someone links to a Github or Gitlab repo in a Stackoverflow post, or a Github or Gitlab gist, is the contained content CC-BY-SA? Let's say I am the sole author of the code on Github/Gitlab?

For a second senario: Let's say I am one of several authors in a Github/Gitlab repo, and the code is MIT licensed? Does the code still have to be CC-BY-SA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. HTML linking does not create a derivative work, so it is irrelevant what license the Stack Overflow post is under, it cannot possibly affect the license of the linked content.

(Otherwise you could never link from a Stack Overflow post to anything proprietary)

Comment: Correct : Otherwise , we can link to Proprietary Stuff ( owned by somebody else , Eg YouTube / NYT / ShutterStock ) & a third Party can start using that Proprietary Stuff , claiming that it is CC-BY-SA , with the owner not being aware of that.